# FilamentPHP - How create a relationship in the same modal

Tags: relationship, laravel-9, laravel-filament

I'm creating an admin panel using FilamentPHP. I have a model for categories, and in this model, I created the structure with id, slug name, and parent_id.

The parent_id is to be filled with the ID of another category that already exists, creating parents and children.

How can I create a select with the existing list of categories in the category create method?  As you can see below, I tried to use it in the form but without success.

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('parent_id'),
            Select::make('categories')
                ->relationship('categories', 'name')
                ->preload()
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do what I needed in a way, let's say, more elegant! and I want to leave as an example.

```
Select::make('parent_id')
    ->options(Category::query()->pluck('name', 'id'))
    ->preload()
```

Answer (score 0):

use the new option in the select option modal.

```
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
Select::make('category_id')
    ->relationship(name: 'category', titleAttribute: 'name')
    ->createOptionForm([
        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
            ->required(),
        Forms\Components\TextInput::make('status')
            ->required(),
    ]),
```

Filament will automatically detect the `parent_id` using the eloquent relationship you define in your model.